# Does the spin of an unpaired electron in a sub-shell affect the spin of another unpaired electron in a sub-shell next to the other sub-shell?

Tags: electrons, quantum-spin, physical-chemistry

Does the spin of an unpaired electron in a sub-shell affect the spin of another unpaired electron in a sub-shell next to the other sub-shell?
For example Si 1s2 2s2 2p6 3s2 3p2
Does the unpaired electrons in two different 3p sub-shells affect each other's spin and should they have opposite spins?
[![why are all the arrows representing the spins of singly filled orbitals in the same direction?
Is this true in real life?][1]][1]
Thank you